# How to filter all ad by category name?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, where-clause

My use case is simple:

> Get all ads that have a category name of params[:category_name].

---

Here are my model associations:

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  attr_accessible :anonymous, :celular, :name, :precio, :category_id
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ads

  attr_accessible :name
end
```

Here is my controller code:

```
def by_category
  @ads = Ad.where(:category => params[:category_name])
end
```

But it's not working as intended and I get an exception:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: ads.category: SELECT "ads".* FROM "ads"  WHERE "ads"."category" = 'aeronautica'

How can I filter the ad objects by category name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ads database you only have a column called category_id, so searching the ads database for a category name has no use.

```
 Category.find_by_name(params[:category_name]).ads
```

This would show all ads for a category with the category_name that is in the params.

Comment: Missing parentheses before .ads

Comment: Oops, I should really pay more attention. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Ad.where(:category => Category.find_by_name(params[:category_name]))
```

`params[:category_name]` is only a string, whereas `:category` is an object of type Category.

```
Category.find_by_name
```

will give you a Category object, which you can compare with `:category`

**Edit:**

For this particular case, you could try the following, since you might've used `category_id:integer` instead of `category:reference` for creating the Ad model.

```
Ad.where(:category_id => Category.find_by_name(params[:category_name]).id)
```

Comment: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: ads.category: SELECT "ads".* FROM "ads"  WHERE "ads"."category" IS NULL` - Any ideas?

Comment: When you created the Ads table, did you add a reference to category? Like, `rails g model ad anonymous:integer celular:integer name:string precio:string *category:reference*`   Did you use `category:reference` or `category_id:integer` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Ad.where(:category => {:name => params[:category_name]})
```